# Plural or single form of word in names of variables, classes

Tags: grammatical-number, programming

I am wondering which option is more correct when I want to call some class of objects: NotificationService or Notification**s**Service. Is there difference between them? If so, what is it?

Comment: Thanks! I honestly tried to find answer before adding new question but I had no success. Usually it is needed to know how to do it right :)

Comment: Please note that requests for naming are considered off-topic here, as they are just labels, not really language per se, and ultimately come down to opinion. There is no right or wrong way, linguistically speaking, to name a class or column or function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NotificationService**

Clearly this service is going to involve multiple notifications; whether this is a programming term or not, we would say 'notification service'. In the same way that we have a letterbox, a mousetrap, a wine rack, a programme guide, or a photo album, we don't need to spell out that each object contains or refers to multiple items.

Comment: Except that one of the reasons we sometimes opt for a plural forms in attributive nouns is when we want to emphasize variety, as in *soft drinks manufacturer*. If the notifications included birthday reminders and dental appointments, *notifications* would be justifiable at the very least. Winners bracket, cattle prod, arts degree, ladies man, boys club, parts house, records search, clothes washer.

Comment: I see where you're going, in that you might say _soft drinks manufacturer_ if you wanted to highlight the fact it produces more than one kind of soft drink, but I don't think the example holds up for notifications since if the distinction between types of notification were important you'd want to highlight it in a less subtle way.

Comment: Also, I think _ladies' man_ and _boys' club_ were possessives; _clothes_ doesn't exist as a singular; _arts degree_ means something completely different to a _art degree_ ...